# Visualforce dynamic components causing 'Not serializable' error on form submit

Tags: serialization, visualforce, apex

I have a visualforce page that uses a dynamic component to render some input fields. when a user hits the submit form button, I consistently receive a 'Not serializable: Component.apex.outputPanel' error.

Question is how best to use a dynamic component to render and bind some input fields so the record can then be submitted ? The variable I want to process on submit is declared in the page controller, but I cant get around the serialization error. Any suggestions most appreciated.

Cheers,
CH

Answer (score 0):

Update:

this 'unable to submit a form while dynamic component rendered' remained a problem, so in the end I chose a different approach and whilst still used dynamic component, I avoided submitting the view state per standard salesforce approach, and instead submitted via a javascript remoting function that stringified all dynamic input fields client side, submitted to function which then parsed these out into a new sObject and performed DML. Done.